# load jqmobile.js file for only one page and remove it for other pages

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

My desktop application has one table that has crud pages that were made with JQmobile formating (because its also used on mobile devices).
   When i call any of the crud pages for this process of course i load the JQmobile.js file. Problem is, when i try to call up other desktop pages, JQmobile.js is still loaded, so all subsequent desktop processing requests run with JQmobile formatting. 
   how can i load this JQmobile.js file for only the appropriate processing and then remove it during the rest of subsequent desktop processing request?

```
 to be more specific, I have a 2 bundles like this:     
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Mbsa_JSBundle").Include(
     "~/Scripts/mbsa_Mobile.js",   
     "~/ScriptJQMobile-145/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js" 
    ));

 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Mbsa_CSSBundle").Include(
    "~/Content/mbsa_Mobile.css",
    "~/Content/MbsaMobileStandardCSS/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css",
    "~/ScriptJQMobile-145/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-`1.4.5.css",`
    "~/Content/MbsaMobileStandardCSS/MbsaMobileStandard.css"
    ));
```

Using the example from the user that gave me an answer.
  I would love to do something like this. (but this is a script tag    `within another script tag).`

```
    <body id="pagetag"></body>    
    <script>   

    if($('body').is('#pagetag')){
       if($('body').is('#pagetag')){
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mbsa_CSSBundle")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Mbsa_JSBundle")
       }
    })

     </script>

    // This works ok, but as stated, the scripts remain even 
    // when a non jqmobile formated page is requested.

     @if ((bool)Session["Mbsa-IsMobile"] == false)
        {
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mbsa_DMCSSBundle")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Mbsa_DMJSBundle")
        }
```

How can i remove these bundles once I go to a non jqmobile formated page?

Comment: You can't just remove a script here - once loaded, the objects and functions from a script stay in memory. If your pages have different URLs then maybe you could change your app to navigate using `window.location.href = ...`. Otherwise, you'd have to unload all the jQuery mobile stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

add id or class to body

```
<body id="pagetag">
```

then add a script

```
$(function(){
  if($('body').is('#pagetag')){
   // add whatever scripts you need 
   }
});
```

Comment: user1675557, please see my more specific question in my edited post, thanks!